# How can I write simple data mining queries for the following schemas?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-mining, sqlplus

For the following given schema, can I please guided on how to write simple Data mining queries using oracle with sqlplus?

```
CREATE TABLE Location(Location_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, Location_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (Location_id));


CREATE TABLE Customer(customer_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, customer_name varchar(15) NOT NULL, customer_credit NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (customer_id));


CREATE TABLE Product(product_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, product_name varchar(10) NOT NULL, product_price NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, product_quantity NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (product_id));


CREATE TABLE Supplier(supplier_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, supplier_name varchar(15) NOT NULL, supplier_quantity NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id));


CREATE TABLE Store (customer_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, supplier_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, product_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, location_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,sale NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,category varchar(9) NOT NULL);


ALTER TABLE Store ADD CONSTRAINT Store_fk0 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE Store ADD CONSTRAINT Store_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES Supplier(supplier_id);

ALTER TABLE Store ADD CONSTRAINT Store_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(product_id);

ALTER TABLE Store ADD CONSTRAINT Store_fk3 FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES Location(Location_id);
```

I have the following OLAP query which I wrote which I don't see different from a Data mining query. Also can I be guided on how to write more complex queries for the following:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME,PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME,SALE FROM STORE INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON STORE.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON STORE.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID WHERE STORE.SALE = (SELECT MAX(SALE) FROM STORE);
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague to have a good answer. Please refer to [Oracle Data Mining](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/odm/overview/index.html) for more info about Data Mining.
Data Mining start from a simple query like:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_PREDICTIVE_ANALYTICS.EXPLAIN(
    data_table_name     => 'mining_data_build_v',
    explain_column_name => 'affinity_card',
    result_table_name   => 'ai_explain_output');
END;
/
```

And the skies are the limit...

Comment: thanks for your response @HadyLattouf but I think my question is, can I get an example of how a single query may look like for a data mining process? and how can I write a more complicated OLAP query from what I pasted in here?